# If main is a thread as well in c, why doesn't it run with other threads

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads

I read that main() is single thread itself, so when i create 2 threads in my program like this;

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<pthread.h>
#include<windows.h>

void* counting(void * arg){
    int i = 0;
    for(i; i < 50; i++){
        printf("counting ... \n");
        Sleep(100);

    }
}

void* waiting(void * arg){
    int i = 0;
    for(i; i < 50; i++){
        printf("waiting ... \n");
        Sleep(100);
    }
}

int main(){
    pthread_t thread1;
    pthread_t thread2;
    pthread_create(&thread1, NULL, counting, NULL);
    pthread_create(&thread2, NULL, waiting, NULL);
    pthread_join(thread1, NULL);
    pthread_join(thread2, NULL);

    int i = 0;
    for(i; i < 50; i++){
        printf("maining ... \n");
        Sleep(1000);
    }


}
```

Is main really a thread in that case?
in that case if in main in sleep for some time, shouldn't the main give the CPU to other threads? 
Is main a threads itself here? I am confused a bit here. 
Is there a specific order to main thread execution?

Comment: Put `pthread_join` as the last lines in your code. Now `main` hangs on them.

Comment: Think about what `pthread_join` really does... Take some time to read its manual page.

Comment: if i change pthread_join and make it last statment. It still print the threads first and main last

Comment: The loop in the `main` function will take about 50 seconds (`50` times a one-second sleep), but the threads loops will take only about 5 seconds (`50` times `0.1` second sleep). That means the two created threads will finish *much* faster than the "main" thread. But there should be *some* (a few) `"maining ..."` output mixed in the output of the created threads. You will need to scroll up the output to the top to see it.

Comment: I got a new answer which says "main is not a thread but function"? is that correct @Someprogrammerdude

Comment: The source code symbol `main` *is* a function. But there's also a thread of execution that is running the `main` function. This is often called "the *main* thread". In your program you will have three threads of execution: One running the `counting` function; One running the `waiting` function; And one running the `main` function.

Comment: To be precise: `counting` and `waiting` are no threads either. Threads are entities in the OS and you only tell them which function to execute. Same applies for `main`. That is just the code that happens to be executed by the "main thread" of your program. BTW: You can create hundreds of threads all using the same function.

Comment: Re, "...shouldn't the main give the CPU to other threads?" That's exactly what it does when it calls `pthread_join(t, NULL)`: It gives up it's CPU, and it won't run again until thread `t` is finished.  But just because it isn't running during that time, that doesn't mean it stops being a thread. No different from how a bicycle still is a bicycle even when nobody's riding it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I read that main() is single thread itself

No, you have misunderstood.  Every C program has a *function* named `main()`.  C language semantics of the program start with the initial entry into that function.  In that sense, and especially when you supply the parentheses, `main()`, is a function, not a thread.

However, every process also has a *main thread* which has a few properties that distinguish it from other threads.  That is initially the only thread, so it is that thread that performs the initial entry into the `main()` function.  But it is also that thread that runs all C functions called by `main()`, and by those functions, *etc*., so it is not, in general, specific to running only the code appearing directly in the body of `main()`, if that's what you mean by "main() is a single thread itself".

> , so when i create 2 threads in my program like this; [...] Is main really a thread in that case?

There is really a main thread in that case, separate from the two additional threads that it starts.

> in that case if in main in sleep for some time, shouldn't the main give the CPU to other threads?

If the main thread slept while either of the other two were alive, then yes, one would expect one or both of the others to get (more) CPU time.  And in a sense, that's exactly what happens: the main thread calls `pthread_join()` on each of the other threads in turn, which causes it to wait (some would say "sleep") until those threads terminate before it proceeds.  While it's waiting, it does not contend with the other threads for CPU time, as that's pretty much what "waiting" means.  But by the time the main thread reaches the `Sleep()` call in your program, the other threads have already terminated and been joined, because that's what `pthread_join()` does.  They no longer exist, so naturally they don't run during the `Sleep()`.

> Is main a threads itself here?

There is a main thread, yes, and it is the only one in your particular process that executes any of the code in function `main()`.  Nothing gets executed except in some thread or other.

> I am confused a bit here. Is there a specific order to main thread execution?

As already described, the main thread is initially the only thread.  Many programs never have more than that one.  Threads other than the main one are created only by the main thread or by another thread that has already been created.  Of course, threads cannot run before they are created, nor, by definition, after they have terminated.  Threads execute independently of each other, generally without any predefined order, except as is explicitly established via synchronization objects such as mutexes, via for-purpose functions such as `pthread_join()`, or via cooperative operations on various I/O objects such as pipes.

Answer (score 2):

```
 pthread_join(thread1, NULL);
 pthread_join(thread2, NULL);
```

You asked the thread to wait until `thread1` terminates and then wait until `thread2` terminates, so that's what it does.

Answer (score 1):

`main()` is not a thread but a function, so here's a clear "no" to your initial claim. However, if you read a few definitions of what is a thread, you will find that it is something that can be scheduled, i.e. an ongoing execution of code. Further, a running program will not be able to actually do anything without "ongoing execution of code" without e.g. `main()` as first entrypoint. So, definitely, every code executed by a program is executed by a thread, without exceptions.

BTW: You can retrieve the thread ID of the current thread. Try running that from `main()`. It will work and give you a value that distinguishes this call from calls from other threads.

Comment: Right, `main()` is a function. It is the first function that is called by the first thread of a process.

Comment: @WaqarHaider, Every C program starts with one thread, and almost the first thing that one thread does is, it calls `main(...)`. That is why people often call it the "main thread."